# Team alert for pull request

Tags: git, alert, pull-request, azure-devops

I've created several VSTS groups (not Teams) containing different people. Depending on the affected code different groups should be assigned for pull requests. Now I would like to define a team alert which notifies the people that a new pull request was created and one of the groups where they are member of is assigned as reviewer. Is there a way to define this?

I'm looking for a filter like:
`[Reviewers] Contains [AnyGroupWhereImMemberOf]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, click the dropdown list under "Administrator Actions" and select the group, you can create alert for this group. And in the alert filter, you can set "Reviewers Contains GroupName". The name format should like this: [ProjectName]\GroupName, the same as the one you use when create the pull request.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I tried to setup the alert but receive the following error message (I'm tenant owner and administrator and therefore should have all permissions):

    TF50309: The following account does not have sufficient permissions to complete the operation: [MyProject]\My Group. The following permissions are needed to perform this operation: View project-level information.

Comment: @Pascal You need to the set the permission for this group on "Security" page.